# Dropdown Menus closing when clicking inside of container

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

When I click inside of the dropdown menus, they close.

This occurs at `Login menu` and `nav bar`.

Im not too awfully experienced at webdeveloping but I know that its probably just some dumb error Ive overlooked a million times today.

I believe the error is in this part of the code (expanded bellow):

```
if (e.isDefaultPrevented()) return
      $this.attr('aria-expanded', 'false')
      $parent.removeClass('open').trigger('ontouchstart', relatedTarget)
```

Can be seen at zunelex.com

```js
 var backdrop = '.dropdown-backdrop'
  var toggle   = '[data-toggle="dropdown"]'
  var Dropdown = function (element) {
    $(element).on('click.bs.dropdown', this.toggle)
  }

  Dropdown.VERSION = '3.3.4'

  Dropdown.prototype.toggle = function (e) {
    var $this = $(this)

    if ($this.is('.disabled, :disabled')) return

    var $parent  = getParent($this)
    var isActive = $parent.hasClass('open')

    clearMenus()

    if (!isActive) {
      if ('ontouchstart' in document.documentElement && !$parent.closest('.navbar-nav').length) {
        // if mobile we use a backdrop because click events don't delegate
        $('<div class="dropdown-backdrop"/>').insertAfter($(this)).on('click', clearMenus)
      }

      var relatedTarget = { relatedTarget: this }
      $parent.trigger(e = $.Event('show.bs.dropdown', relatedTarget))

      if (e.isDefaultPrevented()) return

      $this
        .trigger('focus')
        .attr('aria-expanded', 'true')

      $parent
        .toggleClass('open')
        .trigger('shown.bs.dropdown', relatedTarget)
    }

    return false
  }

  Dropdown.prototype.keydown = function (e) {
    if (!/(38|40|27|32)/.test(e.which) || /input|textarea/i.test(e.target.tagName)) return

    var $this = $(this)

    e.preventDefault()
    e.stopPropagation()

    if ($this.is('.disabled, :disabled')) return

    var $parent  = getParent($this)
    var isActive = $parent.hasClass('open')

    if ((!isActive && e.which != 27) || (isActive && e.which == 27)) {
      if (e.which == 27) $parent.find(toggle).trigger('focus')
      return $this.trigger('click')
    }

    var desc = ' li:not(.disabled):visible a'
    var $items = $parent.find('[role="menu"]' + desc + ', [role="listbox"]' + desc)

    if (!$items.length) return

    var index = $items.index(e.target)

    if (e.which == 38 && index > 0)                 index--                        // up
    if (e.which == 40 && index < $items.length - 1) index++                        // down
    if (!~index)                                      index = 0

    $items.eq(index).trigger('focus')
  }

  function clearMenus(e) {
    if (e && e.which === 3) return
    $(backdrop).remove()
    $(toggle).each(function () {
      var $this         = $(this)
      var $parent       = getParent($this)
      var relatedTarget = { relatedTarget: this }

      if (!$parent.hasClass('open')) return

      $parent.trigger(e = $.Event('hide.bs.dropdown', relatedTarget))

      if (e.isDefaultPrevented()) return

      $this.attr('aria-expanded', 'false')
      $parent.removeClass('open').trigger('ontouchstart', relatedTarget)
    })
  }

  function getParent($this) {
    var selector = $this.attr('data-target')

    if (!selector) {
      selector = $this.attr('href')
      selector = selector && /#[A-Za-z]/.test(selector) && selector.replace(/.*(?=#[^\s]*$)/, '') // strip for ie7
    }

    var $parent = selector && $(selector)

    return $parent && $parent.length ? $parent : $this.parent()
  }


  // DROPDOWN PLUGIN DEFINITION
  // ==========================

  function Plugin(option) {
    return this.each(function () {
      var $this = $(this)
      var data  = $this.data('bs.dropdown')

      if (!data) $this.data('bs.dropdown', (data = new Dropdown(this)))
      if (typeof option == 'string') data[option].call($this)
    })
  }

  var old = $.fn.dropdown

  $.fn.dropdown             = Plugin
  $.fn.dropdown.Constructor = Dropdown


  // DROPDOWN NO CONFLICT
  // ====================

  $.fn.dropdown.noConflict = function () {
    $.fn.dropdown = old
    return this
  }


  // APPLY TO STANDARD DROPDOWN ELEMENTS
  // ===================================

  $(document)
    .on('click.bs.dropdown.data-api', clearMenus)
    .on('click.bs.dropdown.data-api', '.dropdown form', function (e) { e.stopPropagation() })
    .on('click.bs.dropdown.data-api', toggle, Dropdown.prototype.toggle)
    .on('keydown.bs.dropdown.data-api', toggle, Dropdown.prototype.keydown)
    .on('keydown.bs.dropdown.data-api', '[role="menu"]', Dropdown.prototype.keydown)
    .on('keydown.bs.dropdown.data-api', '[role="listbox"]', Dropdown.prototype.keydown)
```

```css
.dropdown {
  position: relative;
}
.dropdown-toggle:focus {
  outline: 0;
}
.dropdown-menu {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1000;
  display: none;
  float: left;
  min-width: 160px;
  padding: 5px 0;
  margin: 2px 0 0;
  font-size: 14px;
  text-align: left;
  list-style: none;
  background-color: #fff;
  -webkit-background-clip: padding-box;
          background-clip: padding-box;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .15);
  border-radius: 4px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 6px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, .175);
          box-shadow: 0 6px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, .175);
}
.dropdown-menu.pull-right {
  right: 0;
  left: auto;
}
.dropdown-menu .divider {
  height: 1px;
  margin: 9px 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #e5e5e5;
}
.dropdown-menu > li > a {
  display: block;
  padding: 3px 20px;
  clear: both;
  font-weight: normal;
  line-height: 1.42857143;
  color: #333;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.dropdown-menu > li > a:hover,
.dropdown-menu > li > a:focus {
  color: #262626;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
}
.dropdown-menu > .active > a,
.dropdown-menu > .active > a:hover,
.dropdown-menu > .active > a:focus {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: #337ab7;
  outline: 0;
}
.dropdown-menu > .disabled > a,
.dropdown-menu > .disabled > a:hover,
.dropdown-menu > .disabled > a:focus {
  color: #777;
}
.dropdown-menu > .disabled > a:hover,
.dropdown-menu > .disabled > a:focus {
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: not-allowed;
  background-color: transparent;
  background-image: none;
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(enabled = false);
}
.open > .dropdown-menu {
  display: block !important;
  visibility: visible;
}
.open > a {
  outline: 0;
}
.dropdown-menu-right {
  right: 0;
  left: auto;
}
.dropdown-menu-left {
  right: auto;
  left: 0;
}
.dropdown-header {
  display: block;
  padding: 3px 20px;
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 1.42857143;
  color: #777;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.dropdown-backdrop {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 990;
}
.pull-right > .dropdown-menu {
  right: 0;
  left: auto;
}
.dropup .caret,
.navbar-fixed-bottom .dropdown .caret {
  content: "";
  border-top: 0;
  border-bottom: 4px solid;
}
.dropup .dropdown-menu,
.navbar-fixed-bottom .dropdown .dropdown-menu {
  top: auto;
  bottom: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 2px;
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .navbar-right .dropdown-menu {
    right: 0;
    left: auto;
  }
  .navbar-right .dropdown-menu-left {
    right: auto;
    left: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown-menu" style="padding: 15px;>
     <form class="form-horizontal"  method="post" accept-charset="UTF-8">
     <input id="sp_uname" class="form-control login" type="text" name="sp_uname" placeholder="Username.." />
     <input id="sp_pass" class="form-control login" type="password" name="sp_pass" placeholder="Password.."/>
     <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" name="submit" value="login" />
     </form>
    </li>
    </ul>
    </ul>
   </div>
```

Comment: Your snippet does not work, also your html is invalid, you are missing a `"` after the style attribute in a div.  Can you produce a minimal working example?

Comment: That " was actually the problem. Thanks for accidentally fixing my issue.

Answer (score 0):

Your html is invalid, the style attribute requires an opening **AND** closing quotation mark to be valid.

Essentially your style attribute keeps reading characters until it decides it has a reason to stop so:

`padding: 15px;>`

And then everything after that just gets really messed up.